# How to make a two column div span the full width of the page

Tags: html, css

I would like for the div below to span the entire width of the page but it is currently only spanning the middle part of my page (as is the rest of the content).

I've tried to include `width:100%` in my CSS, I've also tried to remove the container but I can't get both of the columns side-by-side if I do this.

```html
<div class="container full-width">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">

      <h2>What we do.</h2>
      <h4>Put some text in here about what we do just to see what it looks like. </h4>
      <a href="#"><button>Services</button></a>

    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">

      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/logo.png" class="img-fluid logo"> </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing your outermost `.container` to `.container-fluid.`

https://codepen.io/arhoy/pen/NWKMgep?editors=1010

Comment: hmm see updated code pen link. Works for me using the cdn version of bootstrap in the codepen. What version are you using? You also missing a closing div on the row

Comment: You were right - i missed the outermost container! Thanks for your help!